# javascript countdown with start/stop/reset and input time from user

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, countdown

I am basically want the page to take a user input of the time in seconds.

After that I want the countdown to start when the user presses "Start" button
"Pause" when the pause button is pressed.
Also a reset button so that the user can start the countdown from the beginning.

Here is what i got so far:

```
<script>
var CCOUNT;
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnct').click(function() {
            CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
            cdreset();
            });
var t, count;
function cddisplay() {
  document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
};
function countdown() {
    // starts countdown
    cddisplay();
    if (count == 0) {
        // time is up
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    }
};
function cdpause() {
    // pauses countdown
    clearTimeout(t);
};
function cdreset() {
    // resets countdown
    cdpause();
    count = CCOUNT;
    cddisplay();
};
</script>
<body>
 <form id="frm"> 
  Seconds: 
  <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2"/> 
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnct" value="Input"/>
  </form>
<span id="timespan"></span>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset()">
</body>`
```

But its not working, It worked when i left out the user input part and just initialized CCOUNT. But I want the page to take user input.

Comment: Umm... do you ever close the brackets from `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/XZXLk/

Javascript with jQuery

```
var CCOUNT;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnct').click(function () {
        CCOUNT = $('#seconds').val();
        cdreset();
    });
});
var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
    document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
}

function countdown() {
    // starts countdown
    cddisplay();
    if (count === 0) {
        // time is up
    } else {
        count--;
        t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
}

function cdpause() {
    // pauses countdown
    clearTimeout(t);
}

function cdreset() {
    // resets countdown
    cdpause();
    count = CCOUNT;
    cddisplay();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="frm">Seconds:
    <input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="0" size="2" maxlength="2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="btnct" value="Input" />
</form>
<span id="timespan"></span>

<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset()">
```

Comment: Double click or triple click the start button. Might want to set a disable/hide function.

Comment: @wrxsti absolutely correct but I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP :-)